# How can I perform a custom action on the data of a DataGridRow when it is selected?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I've been trying to figure out how to get this custom behaviour into a datagrid with out having much look when searching online for solutions.

Given the following datagrid (some xaml removed for brevity):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have the checkbox successfully bound to the databound object for each row. (Note: I'm using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` rather than `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` so that you do not need to double-click to change the value).

What I would like to achieve is to have the ability to tick the checkbox / update the Selected property of the databound object when the user selects a row.  Effectively making the entire row click set the checked property of the checkbox. Ideally, I'd like to do this without a code behind file if possible as I'm trying to keep my code behinds as clean as possible.

Another feature which I would like, if possible, would be that clicking on a row would toggle it's selected property so that if you click on another one, the previous one stays selected as well as the new one.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does your current IsChecked binding to Selected give you a binding error? I think you might be able to do it this way (sorry not near an IDE to test) but you might have to make sure you are binding onto the correct Selected property with maybe a RelativeSource search?

Comment: Selected is the property of the datacontext item (perhaps not the best name) not the datagridrow, so this works fine as intended. I'm trying to additionally bind it to the `datagridrow` isselected but I've not found an examples of binding to this.

Comment: Ah I see, you may have to look at SelectedItem on the DataGrid instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity. I understood

> Another feature which I would like, if possible, would be that
>   clicking on a row would toggle it's selected property so that if you
>   click on another one, the previous one stays selected as well as the
>   new one.

in the way, that you want the CheckBox of the an item, respectively the `Selected` property on the items ViewModel,  to stay selected, when the next DataGridRow is selected, but not the DataGridRow itself? Is that correct?

My suggestion is to extend the behavior of your `DataGrid` using **WPF behavior**s ([This is a good introduction](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html). This way you can keep your codebehind clear, but don't have to twist XAML to make it do what you want.

This is basically the idea of behaviors: Writing testable code, which is not coupled to your concrete view, but nonetheless allowing you to write complicated stuff in 'real' code and not in XAML. In my opinion your case is a typical task for behaviors.

Your behavior could look about as simple as this.

```cs
public class CustomSelectionBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        // Set mode to single to be able to handle the cklicked item alone
        AssociatedObject.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Single;
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Get DataContext of selected row
        var item = args.AddedItems.OfType<ItemViewModel>();

        // Toggle Selected property
        item.Selected = !item.Selected;
    }
}
```

Attaching the behavior to your specific DataGrid, is done in XAML:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:CustomSelectionBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

You need to reference

```
System.Windows.Interactivity.dll
```

which contains the `Behavior<T>` baseclass as well.

Comment: This works perfectly, and just needs a few tweaks to get my desired behavior, but makes it nice and simple!